# Airflow variable masking the value "airflow"

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I am exploring airflow variables and created a variable in Airflow whose value has the word 'airflow' in it:

```
var_source_path = /opt/airflow/
```

While using this variable in my task, the word airflow is being masked with asterisk (***) as below:

Task:

```
t1 = BashOperator(task_id = 'echo_source_path',
                    bash_command = 'echo {{ var.value.var_source_path }}',
                    dag = dag
                    )
```

Log:

```
[2022-01-24 12:56:45,937] {subprocess.py:63} INFO - Running command: ['bash', '-c', 'echo /opt/***/']
[2022-01-24 12:56:45,948] {subprocess.py:75} INFO - Output:
[2022-01-24 12:56:45,982] {subprocess.py:79} INFO - /opt/***/
[2022-01-24 12:56:45,984] {subprocess.py:83} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
```

What is the reason behind this behaviour. Is there any config to control this.

P.S: I have set the Airflow metadata user/password as airflow:

```
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: airflow
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: airflow
      MYSQL_USER: airflow
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: airflow
      MYSQL_DATABASE: airflow
```

Is this the root cause of this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow 2.1+ masks sensitive passwords by default.

It means that (indeed) you are using `airflow` as password somewhere (which you should not)

See here for description on how it works and how you can disable it:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/secrets/mask-sensitive-values.html

Comment: The page says that "Airflow will by default mask Connection passwords and sensitive Variables and keys from a Connection’s extra (JSON) field" . I have "airflow" as the password of the Airflow metadata DB not any connection's password.

Comment: Feel free to make PR to correct it !